# File on heroku not found

Tags: node.js, heroku, filesystems

I have a single-page application which is written in NodeJS and deploy on Heroku.

I define my Procfile like:

web: PORT=$PORT webpack -p --config ./config/webpack/serverProd.js --progress && node ./dist/server.js

The reason why I do not use heroku-postbuild deploy hook is because I can not get the PORT variable which is assigned by Heroku dynamically, and this is the only way I can access PORT variable.

But when I run `heroku run bash` and search around in the container of Heroku...

ta da!

I can not found my `server.js` which it should be exist in the `/app/dist/` directory.

I am pretty sure there is something I misunderstand. Can anyone point that out?

Really appreicate!

Comment: Have you checked the your app log on Heroku?

Comment: @oneturkmen yes I do check my logs. In fact, I can some of the error message at `/app/dist/server.js` with `heroku logs -t`. But I still can not find file server.js. Is there any other clues I can check in my log?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I setup my nodejs\npm project on heroku

Procfile

```
 web: npm run build && node dist/index.js
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf dist && mkdir dist",
    "serve": "node dist/index.js",
    "start": "nodemon --inspect src/index.js --exec babel-node",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build-server",
    "build-server": "babel src -d dist",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-register"
  },
```

Try to start the app from dist/server.js instead of ./dist/server.js